# How to add sheets using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I would like to apply, header_column and column_format to any new sheets. Also like to use add new sheet. If the sheet name exist, then over write the data. If the sheet doesn't, create a new sheet and add data. here is the code, but it seems it doesn't add new sheet and overwrites the first sheet.

```
def write_xlsx(filename, sheetname, data):

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)

workbook  = writer.book

# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=False, startrow=1, header=False)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheetname]
# Set the column widths
worksheet.set_column('B:E', 35)

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num + 0, value)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Firstly you need to read all sheets that exist in your file. After that you can iterate to check if that sheetname that you are passing as param exist or not and put your logic inside that.
To add new sheet you need to use workbook.add_worksheet()

Comment: hi, what i need to change within my code, can you provide a example? thanks